# input data must be numeric

Tags: r, database, numeric

I am trying to calculate tumor growth rates with the tumgr package using the attahced dataset

```
library(readxl)
 sampleData <- read_excel("C:/Users/user/Downloads/sampleData.xlsx")
 View(sampleData)
install.packages("tumgr")
 library(tumgr)

 par(mfrow=c(3, 2))
 out <- gdrate(sampleData, 0.05, TRUE)
```

```
inputprep(input) error: all input data must be numeric
```

But all data is numeric, so I cannot find how to solve this. Can you help me? I expect output on growth rate

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Sadly we can't help you.  You say all your data are numeric, but that directly contradicts the error message.  Since we don't have access to your data, we don't know whether your statement is incorrect or the error message is incorrect.  (But I know where my money is!) You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Specifically, please post the result of `dput(head(sampleData))` to your question.